# How do I save as a template in Photoshop CS4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, template-design

I've been making my templates by just saving a psd file but that brings up the problem that I might save over the template on accident.

When I go to File> I don't see a "Save as Template" option. Is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Photoshop has no inherent template format.**

That being posted your operating system may have an option.

On the MacOS, you can choose File > Get Info on a file of practically any type, including .psd and tick the "Stationary Pad" option in the Finder. This will cause a *copy* of the file to open when chosen. Same basic operation as a template format.

[image: stationary pad]

I wouldn't know if this is possible on Windows. But surely it must be.